# Send wirelessly very small amount of data

Tags: communication, wireless

I need to transfer wirelessly a message of maximum 5 bytes of data (including everything such as start bits, stop bits etc etc).

**What I tried:**
Empty Ethernet package is at least 56 bytes according to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1846077/size-of-empty-udp-and-tcp-packet)
Empty SMS PDU mode is bigger than 5 bytes according to [this link](http://www.gsm-modem.de/sms-pdu-mode.html)

Are there any other options?
Considering that I'm pretty much a beginner into wireless communications:
Is it even possible to do it without reinventing the wheel?
Are there any devices that can send only as few bytes as I need?

Distance: in the order of kilometers, but a few meters is ok too for now

Comment: Why do you have this limit of 5 bytes total (including any transport layer overhead)

Comment: Is the data so urgent that you can't buffer it, and combine 11 @ 5 bytes into one 55 byte, plus one spare? And, more importantly, what  -specifically - is the problem if sending less data than could be transmitted? The energy would be the same, so I am guessing financial cost somehow - are you transmitting over 3/4G or satellite?

Comment: I need to send a message from a moving train to the control dispatch and the message must not be bigger in size than 5 bytes. This is for a school project and I think this requirement is just way to hard to implement for a student. @Mawg I still have to find a way of transmitting the data (3g/4g/RF it doesn't matter)

Comment: I think you may be overthinking or have gotten hold of the wrong end of the stick. I strongly urge you to ask whomever set you the assignment. Especially, clarify where he wants those 5 bytes of data measured. I think they key phrase is “***user*** data”.  Take a look at my OSI 7 layer model. If layer 7 wants to pass 5 bytes of data, it has to pass it down through the stack to layer 1 who will actually transmit it. It passes it to layer 6 who adds its own header, which can be understood only by layer 6 on the other side of the interface and treat the 5 bytes of layer 7 data as payload ... ->

Comment: It then passes it down to layer 5, who repeats the process. At the bottom, layer 1 passes to layer 1, who passes it back up the stack, with each layer stripping its own header, before passing the payload upwards until the original 5 bytes arrive at  layer 7. In terms you may know: if I enter my name on a form, the HTTP layer adds a n HTTP header and passes it down to TCP (or UDP), which adds its own header and passes it down to IP … I guess that the requirement is just to see if you can correctly define a data structure to pass all the required data in 5 bytes. Clarify this before proceeding.

Comment: @Mawg The teacher is a dickhead as I already developed the circuit which includes a IC and GSM modem and developed the source code to send the SMS and receive it to the other end. After I did everything he tells me that the transmitted message size is bigger because the phone number is attached to my 5 byte message.

Comment: Now the only different option that I'm thinking of is to build some kind of RF circuit that sends a radio square wave signal and another one that receives that radio signal. But as I was saying this seems too hard because the message transmitting and receiving is only a small part of the whole project.

Comment: Withhold your number when sending? ;-) Btw, if you can't cram all your data into 5 bytes, use the 5 bytes to send an index into a look-up table that the recipient can use to retrieve the data. One thing about PITAs like your instructor is that they make you think. When you have finished this, you will have learned a lot (especially to take no more of their courses).

Comment: Are you the only one on the course? What are others doing? Will the tutor give a hint, after you explain all that you have tried & that you are no just asking for the answer?

Comment: I'm actually the first who got this far with the project. I will ask for some tips and hopefully I'll not receive some abstract answers. Thank you for your help.

Comment: @Codrut, why would you say that the teacher is a dickhead? .... you obviously did not meet the requirement of the assignment by sending a message longer than 5 bytes ..... you have not completed the development of the project as you claim ..... development includes a testing phase, which happens to have failed

Comment: Possibly because it cannot be done - by the teacher's way of measuring things? Seriously - if he is courting the length of the sending telephone number when sending a 5 byte SMS, he is decidedly a pedant. When the OP says "I'm actually the first who got this far with the project", that speaks volumes. @Codrut, I wish that I could help you more. Please, come back and tell us how this turns out. If I were you, and most failed to complete the exercise, I would be considering pointing that fact out to the instructor's boss. Perhaps you could get some advice on https://academia.stackexchange.com/ ?

Comment: Update: the teacher raised the 5 bytes limit to something manageable after I showed him what I tried and how hard would be to cram everything in 5 bytes.

Comment: Maybe consider using [LoRA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LoRa), [DASH7](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DASH7), or [MIoTy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MIoTy).

Answer (score 3):

If the environment is suitable I suggest you to try data-over-sound and shock your teacher :)
This will transmit **really** 5 bytes. You just need a cheap speaker and microphone.

- [ggwave](https://github.com/ggerganov/ggwave)
- [quiet](https://github.com/quiet/quiet-js) iOS, Android, JS
- [Chirp](https://github.com/chirp) discontinued